# How to Calculate the effective address?

Tags: assembly, x86

suppose you have this instruction in assembly Nasm

```
MOV EAX, [label1] ; label1 is at location 0x00D5A360
```

how do you calculate the effective address is it  ^ the location above.

I know for fact that the addressing mode is Direct.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Nasm. In MIPS assembler, jump commands to labels use a relative value - i.e. the number of lines between the current line and the line the label is on. NASM seems quite different from simple MIPS though, and I don't even know what this MOV command does with a label.

Comment: There is no calcolation! 32bit number (0x00D5A360) as second part of instruction **MOV EAX** directly point to the memory location.

Answer (score 6):

In nasm `label` refers to the address of label while `[label]` retrieves the value stored there. So you can do:

```
    mov eax, label1      ; eax <- 0x00D5A360
```

Or use the versatile `lea` (load effective address):

```
    lea eax, [label1]    ; eax <- 0x00D5A360
```

Or are you asking HOW the assembler determines the effective address? Because that is handled in combination by the assembler, optionally a linker and the loader. Usually your code will compile into an intermediate object format with [relocations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_%28computer_science%29) and the linker or loader will handle calculating the effective address of `label1` for you.

Comment: well what im asking is what the method is to calculate the effective address from the assembler for example the example line i posted 
MOV EAX, [label1] ; label1 is at location 0x00D5A360 
now the effective address would be : 0x00d5a360

Comment: @Shawnricshawnawic: Well then the second of my answer is relevant. Depending on the environment / output format of nasm it'll either be statically determined (you can influence this with the `ORG` directive) or at link time (with extern symbols) or at runtime (again extern symbols).

Comment: perfect thanks i understand i also learned a new technique "lea" LOAD EFFECTIVE ADDRESS who would have thought LOL thank you very much , i think i can handle it from here  :)

Answer (score 0):

From the "Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manual: Volume 2":

```
LEA r16, m ; Store effective address for m in register r16.
LEA r32, m ; Store effective address for m in register r32.
LEA r64, m ; Store effective address for m in register r64.
```

Computes the effective address of the second operand (the source operand) and stores it in the first operand (destination operand). The source operand is a memory address (offset part) specified with one of the processor's addressing modes; the destination operand is a general-purpose register.

Examples:

```
; indirect addressing mode
MOV EBX, label1   ; copy the address of label1 to EBX
MOV [EBX], 100    ; store 100 at the location pointed to by EBX

; using LEA
LEA EBX, [label1] ; stores the effective address of label1 in EBX
MOV [EBX], 100    ; store 100 at the location pointed to by EBX
```

The difference between the two is that `LEA` computes the effective address at runtime, whereas the `MOV` version resolves the effective address at assembly time.

Comment: so basically what your saying is just type LEA and then print the effective address to the screen ? is there any by hand method to do this , with the use of a computer